# Pattern to delete lines causes the whole contents of the file to be deleted in Sed

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I am seeing this weird issue in my script. I have a perl script where I am trying to delete lines containing a pattern.

```
system ("sed '/_pattern_>/d' _path_to_file_ -i");
```

But this delete all the lines from the file. I am confused? Am I doing something wrong?

Adding the PERL code here:

```
#!/bin/env iperl
my $size = shift @ARGV || 500; # sample size
my @sample;
my $ldc_pa_tlist = "_path_to_list1_";

system ("p4 revert $ldc_pa_tlist");
sysem ("p4 sync   $ldc_pa_tlist");
system ("p4 edit   $ldc_pa_tlist");

open FH1, "<", "_Master_List_" or die "Couldn't open file : $! \n";
open FH2, ">", $ldc_pa_tlist or die "Couldn't open file : $! \n";

my $taken = 0; # for making sure we get the first $size lines

while( my $line =  <FH1> ) {
   chomp $line;
  if ( rand(1) < ($size/$.) ){
    my $position;
    do{
    $position = int rand($size);
  }
  while( $taken < $size && $sample[$position] );
    $sample[$position] = $line;
    $taken++;
  }
}

system ("sed '/2frame/d' $ldc_pa_tlist -i");

while ( my $out_line = <FH2> )  {
  next unless ($out_line =~ m/_some_pattern_/);
  for( my $i = 0; $i < @sample; $i++ ){
    print FH2 "$sample[$i] add_opt=\"-2frame\" add_opt=\"-mr_freq_shift:0\"\n";
  }
  last; #exit while loop
}

close FH1;
close FH2;
```

Thank You

Comment: Works for me. Can you post a minimum example showing the problem?

Comment: Add your pattern to your question.

Comment: Why but why you use sed in a perl script!?

Comment: added the perl script and pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I am fairly new to this

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here:

- you are truncating a file and expecting it to have data
- you are trying to open a file twice (once within Perl and once outside of it)
- you're trying to read from a file opened for writing
- you have a race condition

To start, when you do:

```
open FH2, ">", $ldc_pa_tlist or die "Couldn't open file : $! \n";
```

you are opening a file for output and truncating the file to be empty (that's what `">"` does for the `open` function.

After opening the file in Perl, you are then opening it again when you run the `sed` command with the `-i` flag: `system ("sed '/2frame/d' $ldc_pa_tlist -i");`.  You don't want to open the same file for modification at the same time from two different programs.

Basically, when you run that `sed` command `sed` is opening the specified file read-only and opening a new temporary file read-write.  It is reading in the original file, processing to delete any matching lines, and writing the results to the new temporary file.  `sed` then closes both files and moves (renames) the new temporary file to replace the original filename.  If you had the original file opened somewhere else (like you do), you now get a file that's been deleted from the filesystem and will cease to exist when you close the file descriptor.

When you've opened the file already in another program, you are working on a different file than `sed` has output.

Your best bet would be to use Perl to replace the `sed` functionality.  Depending on the size of the file, it may be easiest to read the contents of the whole file into memory, remove the entries you don't want, and then write it back.  If the file is too large to process that way, you can do it similar to `sed`, open a file for reading and a file for writing, and read from the input, filtering out lines that you don't want, and write them to the output.

Also, as hinted at above, you probably want to replace:

```
open FH2, ">", $ldc_pa_tlist or die "Couldn't open file : $! \n";
```

with:

```
open FH2, "+<", $ldc_pa_tlist or die "Couldn't open file : $! \n";
```

That will open the file for reading and writing, but won't clobber it (delete the contents) when you open it.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher for the detailed explanation. I will make the suggested changes.